# How to do well in Computational theory courses?

Tags: complexity-theory

I'm having a lot of trouble solving problems in my Comp Theory class. I just have no idea how to formulate arguments for certain things like proving the concatenation of two non reg langs can have reg languages, or whatever. I know it sounds cliche and really corny, but I don't want to just google the answers. It may be fine for doing well on an assignment, but I know for a fact that I'm not getting the benefits of actually failing over and over again, and then solving the problem. However, most of the time I don't even know how to fail. I just can't even approach a problem. I just look at it, and have no idea on how to approach it.

For those who have taken this class and were just as lost as I am, how did you get through it?

Comment: That class requires (a) familiarity with "proving stuff", and (b) it normally is *totally new* material to students. The only way is to go to class, ask when you get lost, study the material, and (yes, it's allowed) look up answers, but *study* and *understand* them. Sites like this one can help you over bumps, but they will be of use only if you first look around for similar questions, and do a serious effort to solve it yourself.

Comment: what are the prerequisites for the class? those should be enough...